# Auto-format an html file

Tags: html

Is there a way to auto-format (in terms of things like indentation etc) the entire buffer or a region in an html file?

Comment: `indent-buffer` or `indent-region` will do that according to the mode rules. Please be more specifc with what you want to do.

Comment: For example, (in Firefox) view-source:https://www.duolingo.com/learn has just 1 single line for the entire html code. I want to be able to make it readable in emacs.

Comment: You may want to try [yasuyk/web-beautify](https://github.com/yasuyk/web-beautify) to unminify HTML, CSS or JavaScript/JSON.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.